# What is wrong in this code here

Tags: python, join, split

I have given a line of input string like string ="jdjf"
I want to print `j-d-j-f`

```
l=string.split("")
print("-".join(l))
```

Comment: You didn't put the `-` in the string you're joining with.

Comment: sorry it was typo I edited this still showing error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`split` is not working on empty separators. Just use the string:

```
print("-".join(string))
```